# How can I connect a new thermostat wire to a furnace without terminal screws?

Tags: wiring, hvac

I am installing a wifi thermostat. The old one did not have wifi and no C wire is in the wall so I put the G wire in the C slot. On the furnace panel the C slot is occupied and the problem is they connect to the panel with a clip that slides in, not a screw terminal. How do I add the G wire to the terminal with the existing wire with this clip?

Comment: Please show a photo or do a better job of explaining what "a clip that slides in" would be. Do you mean a [blade connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTON_terminal)?

Comment: Does your system not have a fan?  Is it only heat, with hot water or steam?

Comment: Is AC and heat, electric only system. I will try to add a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a single zone, just splice the new thermostat's wires into the existing wires, in parallel with the old thermostat. ("Wire OR" -- if either thermostat is calling for heat, heat is on.)

If multiple zones exist, decide which zone he new tstat will control and splice in parallel with that.

If multiple zones don't exist but you want them to, talk to a plumber who works on heating systems; some combination of new pipes/valves/pumps and a controller will have to be added

Comment: TBH, this doesn't seem to address _my_ understanding of the OPs question at all, but, since it has a check mark, I guess it did. :shrug: _Most excellent_ mind reading skillz!

Comment: If you really can't find the terminals to connect to, or having a second set of those terminals, connecting tin parallel with the existing wires bypasses that issue.